# Duplicate posts in my custom loop

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions

Hi I have custom post and I am trying to print loop data in foreach loop.
but one post is showing 4 time .any help

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'service_slider', 'posts_per_page' =>5 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
  foreach ($thumbnail as $thumb){
  echo '<div class="item">';
  ?>
  <img class="thumbnail zoom" src="<?php  echo $thumbnail[0];?>" > 
 <?php
  echo '</div>';
  }
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Do you get duplicate images, or posts?

Comment: Jack Johansson @yes I have one post but it's showing 4 post, when two then it's showing 8,any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to loop through the thumbnail, which doesn't make any sense:

```
foreach ($thumbnail as $thumb){
```

And then inside the loop you're referring to `$thumbnail` again anyway:

```
<img class="thumbnail zoom" src="<?php  echo $thumbnail[0];?>" >
```

`wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returns an array that looks like this:

```
array(
    0 => 'http://website.com/path/to/image.jpg', // URL 
    1 => 150, // Width
    2 => 150, // Height
    3 => true // Is a resized version?
);
```

So when you try to loop through that, you're looping through those 4 values. But since you use `$thumbnail[0]` in the loop, it's just going to echo that first value 4 times.

And since you're doing this all inside `while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();` you're going to echo the URL for the featured image 4 times for each post.

This would be the simplest approach:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type'      => 'service_slider', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail', false, array( 'class' => 'thumbnail zoom' ) );
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```

`while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();` is looping through the posts. You won't need a `foreach` at all. Then inside that loop I've output the item `div` and the post's featured image.

Note that I've used [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), which outputs the fill image tag for the current post thumbnail (because I passed it `get_post_thumbnail_id()`. The 4th parameter lets you pass an image class to use. This function all also automatically pull in the alt text, which is good for accessibility.